# AWS Step Function - how to receive input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, amazon-rekognition

I have the below step function and I'm trying to pass the ARN to the StartProjectVersion step in the "test" variable using "ProjectVersionArn": "$.test".  Every time I execute the step functions, StartProjectVersion fails with:

> 2 validation errors detected: Value '$.test' at 'projectVersionArn'
> failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression
> pattern: (^arn:[a-z\d-]+:rekognition

How can I set the ARN using $.test?  Thank you.

[image: Step function steps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters): For key-value pairs where the value is selected using a path, the key name must end in `.$`.

```json
"ProjectVersionArn.$": "$.test"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing.