# use variable in map ItemReader

Tags: aws-step-functions

I'm trying to pass a variable to the ItemReader in my "Map" state, like this:

```
  "ItemReader": {
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:getObject",
    "Parameters": {
      "Bucket": "inventorybucket",
      "Key": "$.inventoryKey"
    },
```

But I'm getting the feeling that variables arent "unpacked" at all. Anyone know if this is possible with Step Functions Map?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Step Function - how to receive input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646039/aws-step-function-how-to-receive-input)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `.$` to the parameter "Key", to explicitly indicate that it is a variable

```
"ItemReader": {
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::s3:getObject",
"Parameters": {
  "Bucket": "inventorybucket",
  "Key.$": "$.inventoryKey"
},
```